# ASP.NET Core not serving robots.txt

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my Startup class' `Configure` method I have the following setup for a single-page application that's built separately:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.Run(async (context) =>
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
    await context.Response.SendFileAsync(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "index.html"));
});
```

Then, in the wwwroot of the app I have a robots.txt file (same level as my JS/CSS files). The JS/CSS files are served fine by the static files middleware, but requests to robots.txt always falls through to the catch-all middleware.

How can I make it serve robots.txt as a static file too?

Comment: can you try passing options to UseStaticFiles and setting `ServeUnknownFileTypes`  to true? (see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1 )

Comment: if that's it: you should not rely on that option, but rather make 'robots.txt' "known"

Comment: It's still the same with `ServeUnknownFileTypes = true`.

Comment: You need to install the AspNetCore.SEOHelper package

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these lines to your Configure method:

```
using AspNetCore.SEOHelper;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   // add these two lines to those you already have
   app.UseRobotsTxt(env.ContentRootPath);
   app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

You will need to install the AspNetCore.SEOHelper package

Comment: My .NET6 Program.cs doesn't have the method declarations, so it was a case of installing the Nuget, then after ```var app = builder.Build();```, adding ```app.UseRobotsTxt(app.Environment.ContentRootPath);```